# How to write Ruby on Rails validations dependant on multiple attributes of a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Let's say I have a model class with 3 attributes. I'd like to make sure that at least one of the three is present.

Do I have to write a custom validation for this? Or is there a way to do this with an existing validation helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom validation in your model would be the cleanest way in my opinion:

```
class Model
  validate :at_least_one_present

  def at_least_one_present
    if(they_dont_exist)
      errors.add("need at least one of these fields")
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: [Creating custom validation methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to write a custom validator for this.  All you need to do is subclass `ActiveModel::Validator` and implement a `validate(record)` method, which adds to the record's `errors` hash in the event of an error:

```
class YourValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(record)
        if (your_failure_condition_here)
            record.errors[:base] << "Your error message"
        end
    end
end
```

And then use the validator in your model like so (assuming you've appropriately loaded your validator class):

```
class YourModel
    validates_with YourValidator
end
```